# Area under graph and integration of dx

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives, definite-integrals

Integrating $dx$ within the bounds of $x_1$ and $x_2$ would result in $x_2-x_1.$ How does this make sense in terms of area under the graph?

Comment: $\mathrm{d}x$ = $1 \,\mathrm{d}x$, so you are integrating the constant function, $1$.

Comment: The symbol $\int_{x_1}^{x_2}dx$ is just a shorthand for $\int_{x_1}^{x_2}1 \, dx$, which is the area under the graph of a rectangle with a base of $x_2-x_1$ and height of $1$. Try drawing a picture.